# Manually adding snippets to react-ace editor

Tags: javascript, code-snippets, ace-editor, react-ace

Is it possible to manually add snippets through [react-ace](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace) component.

For example, adding snippet `myFun` to `javascript`:

```
# Function
snippet myFun
    function ${1?:function_name}(${2:argument}) {
                let x = 'test';
        ${3:// body...}
    }
```

I went through the documentation,FAQ ,similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26089258/ace-editor-manually-adding-snippets) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891328/ace-editor-adding-snippet-with-new-line-character).

Comment: In 2019, this answer may be of use to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58377763/how-do-i-programmatically-add-a-snippet-in-ace-editor/58377764#58377764

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging the source code, it is possible with `ace.define(..)`:

```
import ace from 'brace';
import snippet from '../lib/json-snippet'

ace.define('ace/snippets/json', ['require', 'exports', 'module'], (e,t,n) => {
  (t.snippetText = snippet), (t.scope = 'json');
});
```

### Snippet example:

```
const snippet = '# AddNode\n\
snippet addn\n\
    {\n\
        "nodeName": "${1:node_name}",\n\
        "algorithmName": "${2:algo_name}",\n\
        "input": []\n\
    }\n\
';

export default snippet;
```

Check out a demo [here](https://github.com/denvash/react-json-snippet-editor).